# Php Ajax Live Search with multiple value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have here a Php Ajax Live search. What I need to do is add another element or dropdown to search. How I can add the dropdown value in the script?

```
<input type="text" name="value1" id="value1">

<select id="value2" name="value2">
<option value="" selected="selected" disabled>Select an option...</option>
<option value=""></option>
<option value=""></option>
</select>

<div id="result" class="box1"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery_1_9_1(document).ready(function () {
    function load(query) {
        jQuery_1_9_1.post('search.php', {
            value1: query
        }, function (search_bid) {

            jQuery_1_9_1('#result').stop(true, true).fadeIn(200).html(search_bid);

        }); //End ajax call
    }

    load(jQuery_1_9_1("#value1").val());
    //Live search
    jQuery_1_9_1("#value1").on('keyup', function () {
        //Input field value
        load(jQuery_1_9_1(this).val());
    }); //End on function
}); //End document.ready state
</script>
```

Search.php

```
if(isset($_POST['value1'])) {
$search = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['value1']);
$search = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', $search);
$search = $_POST['value1'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to edit your JS to pass in the dropdown's value (You will notice that I also made some changes to avoid duplicate code):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function load() {
        jQuery_1_9_1.post('search.php', {
            value1: jQuery_1_9_1('#value1').val(),
            value2: jQuery_1_9_1('#value2').val()
        }, function (search_bid) {

            jQuery_1_9_1('#result').stop(true, true).fadeIn(200).html(search_bid);

        }); //End ajax call
    }

    jQuery_1_9_1(document).ready(function () {
        // Call load function whenever input or select changes
        jQuery_1_9_1("#value1, #value2").on('change', load);

        load();
    }); //End document.ready state
</script>
```

Now you can access both values in search.php

```
$value1 = $_POST['value1'];
$value2 = $_POST['value2'];
```